# Merge data on multiple rows in one

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table(MySQL) which stores the utilization of users. Now, what I want to do is, get the total utilization per day for each user. I can get data for each user, however, I am finding it really difficult to merge data from multiple rows for a single day.

Right now, the data I get is as :

```
id       date                        download    upload  
1        2015-10-28 08:05:10         1           5
2        2015-10-28 10:25:15         2           5
3        2015-10-28 11:25:10         3           4
4        2015-10-29 11:25:10         8           5
5        2015-10-29 11:25:10         2           7
6        2015-10-29 11:25:10         1           3
7        2015-10-30 11:25:10         11          10
8        2015-10-30 11:25:10         4           5
9        2015-10-30 11:25:10         5           1
10       2015-10-30 11:25:10         10          1
```

But what I want it to appear like is :

```
    id       date                        download    upload  
    1        2015-10-28                  6           14
    4        2015-10-29                  11          15
    7        2015-10-30                  30          17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, DATE(`date`) AS 'date', 
       SUM(download) AS download, SUM(upload) AS upload
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

The query uses [**DATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function in order to extract the date value from the `date` field.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cab1a6/2)

Comment: Can I add a `WHERE` clause here, `where username = $username`

Comment: @prakashchhetri Yes, you can add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Great. It worked. Thanks a lot. Now I am just trying to solve it in a standard codeigniter way. Any ideas?

Comment: @prakashchhetri I'm afraid I can't help you with codeigniter, since I have no knowledge of it.

Comment: Ok. What about getting data between two dates only.

Comment: @prakashchhetri Use `WHERE date BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123040/discussion-between-prakashchhetri-and-giorgos-betsos).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
select id, date(`date`) `date`, sum(download) `download`, sum(upload) `upload`
from your_table
group by date(`date`)
order by `date`
```

It will sum all the downloads & uploads grouping by the date.

Answer (score 0):

you need to a simple sql query lik this:

```
select max(user_id),op_date,sum(download_count) from test group by op_date;
```

data:
1   1   09-SEP-16   2
2   1   09-SEP-16   1
5   1   09-SEP-16   3
4   1   10-SEP-16   2
3   1   10-SEP-16   4

filtered data:

1   09-SEP-16   6
1   10-SEP-16   6

Answer (score 0):

Use group by command

```
select id,`date`,sum(download) as 'download',sum(upload) as 'upload' 
from ur_table 
group by date(`date`)
```